# New to linux, need to find and install my wireless driver AC-8260

Tags: wireless, drivers

I am newish to Linux. I have dual booted on old laptops and I managed to get my wireless driver working back then by downloading it and installing but I cannot remember how i managed that.

I am worried that there is no driver for my wireless card:

GIGABIT LAN & WIRELESS INTEL® **AC-8260** M.2 (867Mbps, 802.11AC)

I'm looking for a linux driver from intel and i'm worried there isn't one available;

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/86068/Intel-Dual-Band-Wireless-AC-8260

Please could someone help me out. I bought a new laptop without windows installed, hoping to get involved with Linux and learn all about it and I'm struggling at the first hurdle!

```
sudo rfkill
Usage:  rfkill [options] command
Options: --version show version (0.5-1ubuntu1 (Ubuntu))
Commands: help event list [IDENTIFIER] block IDENTIFIER unblock IDENTIFIER where IDENTIFIER is the index no. of an rfkill switch or one of: 
<idx> all wifi wlan bluetooth uwb ultrawideband wimax wwan gps fm nfc
```

I have the wifi option in the top right corner, but nothing is happening. Wifi is ok on my other laptop.

**lspci -nnk | grep**

```
0280 -A2 01:00.0 Network controller 
[0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 
[8086:24f3] (rev 3a) Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260 [8086:0010]
```

Comment: Most of the time, simple or core devices like WiFi cards just work. There's no need for a driver installation in most cases. If Intel doesn't have one, one of Ubuntu's generic ones probably does the job.

Comment: Maybe i am missing something then. The wireless card does not seem to be activated on ubuntu. I can turn it on and off from the laptop keyboard, i see the light come one so I know its activated.

Can you suggest anything else i can look at?

Comment: Try running `sudo rfkill` and seeing if it shows up there. Everything should be on.

Comment: Does it not get recognized by Ubuntu (you don't see a WiFi icon in the menubar)? Or can you not connect to anything?

Comment: gregor@Grego:~$ sudo rfkill 
[sudo] password for gregor: 
Usage: rfkill [options] command 
Options: 
 --version show version (0.5-1ubuntu1 (Ubuntu)) 
Commands: 
 help 
 event 
 list [IDENTIFIER] 
 block IDENTIFIER 
 unblock IDENTIFIER 
where IDENTIFIER is the index no. of an rfkill switch or one of: 
 <idx> all wifi wlan bluetooth uwb ultrawideband wimax wwan gps fm nfc

Sorry that didn't format well.

Yeah i have the wifi option in the top right corrner, but nothing is happening, wifi is ok on my other laptop.

Comment: I think we have a driver! First, let's identify your device: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: gregor@Grego:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2 
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a) 
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260 [8086:0010] 


Thank you for taking the time to help the new guy :)


What do i do next?

Comment: Your device is covered by the driver `iwlwifi` in newer Ubuntu versions. Please verify: `modinfo iwlwifi | grep 24F3 | grep 0010` One of the lines should include: `pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00000010bc*sc*i*` Is that what you see? What is your kernel version? `uname -r`

Comment: alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00000010bc*sc*i* 

3.19.0-25.generic


Thanks for the fast replys

Answer (score 7):

I suspect your device simply needs firmware. Verify:

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
dmesg | grep iwl
```

There should be a message that the needed firmware is not found. If so, please download this file to your desktop: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-8000-ucode-25.30.13.0.tgz as well as this: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-8000-ucode-15.227938.0.tgz Right-click each and select 'Extract Here.' Now, back to the terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop/iwlwifi-8000-ucode-25.30.13.0
sudo cp iwlwifi*  /lib/firmware
cd ~/Desktop/iwlwifi-8000-ucode-15.227938.0
sudo cp iwlwifi*  /lib/firmware
```

Reboot and your wireless should be working. If not, post diagnostics:

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
dmesg | grep iwl
```

Based on your diagnostics, I suggest that you update the driver `iwlwifi`. Download this package to your desktop: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/11/15/backports-20151115.tar.gz Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now, back to the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
cd ~/Desktop/backports-20151115
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.

You have compiled the driver for your current kernel version only. When Update Manager installs a later linux-image, after the required reboot, you must recompile:

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-20151115
make clean
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

Please retain the file and these instructions for that time.

Comment: Hi, still not working. I cant seem to reply with the diagnostic. Its very frustrating, i dont know why comments will not let me reply to you with it.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include the diagnostics.

Comment: [    3.269108] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)

Comment: [    3.270042] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Unsupported splx structure

Comment: [    3.270375] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000B-12.ucode failed with error -2

Comment: [    3.270390] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000B-11.ucode failed with error -2

Comment: [    3.270400] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000B-10.ucode failed with error -2

Comment: [    3.270402] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-8000B-10.ucode' failed.

Comment: [    3.270411] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000B-9.ucode failed with error -2

Comment: [    3.270413] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-8000B-9.ucode' failed.

Comment: Hang on, I'll find the -12 firmware and edit my answer in just a few minutes.

Comment: [    3.270415] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: no suitable firmware found!

Comment: I can find only the firmware versions in my answer. The later version of the driver `iwlwifi` calls for -13 and later. We can update the driver or you can install Ubuntu 15.10, using the later 4.2.0-xx kernel. I will amend my answer to show how to update the driver, but you may, as an alternative, instead install 15.10.

Comment: Boom! I am online now. Thank you so much Chili! Your last suggestion worked (the download, not 15.10). I was worried no one would have the time to help  the new guy but you have truly outdone yourself. 

I will learn linux and look back on this and hope to understand how you fixed my issue:) I'll also make sure to return the karma and help here when i can in the future!

Comment: Awesome! If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: http://askubuntu.com/tour Also, please see my final edit.

Comment: Hi do you have an update to backport for kernel 4.15? It seems missing on that list. I've tried to make backports-4.19-rc5-1 and backports-4.14-rc2-1 but both failed.
here my post: https://askubuntu.com/q/1127216/259316